# How to earn SPECACT in Battlefield - Bad Company 2

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

There are SPECACT Insignia and also certain SPECACT Efficiency/Excellency PINs to achieve in Battlefield Bad Company 2.

How can they be achieved?

I guess this question includes a metaquestion: "What is a SPECACT?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SPECACT parts were added together with a DLC, the SPECACT Assault, Engineer, Medic and Recon individual DLC's, as well as a bundle DLC that included all four.

The SPECACT DLC for a particular class gave you an extra weapon, basically a "SPECACT" version of one of the better weapons for that class, unlocked and ready for you to play with. It also gave you a "Kit" which is basically a different Camo-suite for you to wear.

On the menu, after installing the DLC, you can select either "Assault" or "Assault+" class to select which kit to use. The weapon is available to both classes, but not all game modes.

For the four classes, the weapons are:

- Assault: M16 SA
- Engineer: UMP SA
- Medic: MG3 SA
- Recon: M95 SA

The excellency pins are awared for reaching a  kill count of 8 in any round with the specact weapons.

The efficiency pins are awarded for reaching a kill streak of 5 in any game round with the specact weapons.

The Insignias are awarded for reaching a total kill count across game rounds of 100 with the specact kits.

On Xbox 360 and PS3, there are achievements and trophies that are awared for getting all 3 awards (excellency pin, efficiency pin and insignia) for a particular class. On Xbox 360 these are worth 15GP apiece.

Comment: do you know if they will be available for PC also?

Comment: Call me a noob, but what is a "DLC"?

Comment: I'm not sure, but "DownLoadable Content" fits.

Comment: Yes, sorry that I didn't clarify. DLC is exactly that, downloadable content.

Comment: And sorry, I don't know if or when they will be available for the PC. For all I know, they already are, or perhaps they will never be available.

Comment: Yes, they are available for PC in the EA Store.

Comment: I believe DLC is auto downloaded on the PC

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search shows that they appear to require **[DLC](http://battletracker.com/forum/bad-company-forums/bad-company-2-discussions/200254-new-specact-insignia-and-pins/)** .

Then you need to get:

Insignia:
100 kills using the weapon

Pins:
Excellence pin
8 kills in a round with a weapon

Efficiency Pin
5 kill steak with the weapon

[Source](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/Battlefield/New-pins-amp-insignia/m-p/10702483)